# Does a complex/deeply nested client-side state need to be normalised?

Tags: reactjs, algorithm, data-structures, state, single-page-application

### Background

I am building a single-page-application in React whose data will be retrieved from a relational database. Consider the following two tables:

- menu
- menu_items

A menu has many menu items. Menu items can be related to other menu items (represented in the database as an adjacency list). On the client, I'm representing it as a tree, i.e.:

```json
{
  "id": "menu",
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "item-1",
      "name": "Breakfast",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "id": "item-2",
      "name": "Lunch",
      "children": [{ "id": "item-2-1", "children": [] }]
    }
  ]
}
```

#### UI

A tree can get four levels deep and is typically much wider than it is tall. It is currently rendered recursively in the following way:

```
type Properties = {
  items: {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    children: Properties["items"];
  }[];
};

const Items = ({ items }: Properties) => (
  <ul>
    {items.map((item) => (
      <li key={item.id}>
        {item.name}
        <Items items={item.children} />
      </li>
    ))}
  </ul>
);
```

### Problem

I have reached the stage where I want to update specific nodes in the tree. This operation seems complex, because it involves searching and replacing entire subtrees. Additionally, it will happen often, i.e. `onChange`, as a user updates `item.name`.

Although I don't use Redux, the following article explains it could be better to normalise nested client-side data to make operations like this easier: https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape.

#### Example

```json
const menu = {
  "id": "menu",
  "itemMap": {
    "item-1": { "parentId": null },
    "item-2": { "parentId": null },
    "item-2-1": { "parentId": "item-2" }
  }
}
```

### Question

Would I not have to denormalise/turn it back into a tree to render the UI? If yes, is there any point in my normalising the data?

I don't have a lot of experience with this and am struggling to find the right resources to answer the questions I have.

Comment: "_My main question is, would I not have to denormalise/turn it back into a tree to render the recursive UI?_": I don't see any code related to rendering — so I'm really not sure what kind of response you might be seeking. Can you update the question with a [mre]? See [ask].

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, @jsejcksn. I've updated my question to add more clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with most engineering problems, there isn't a "correct" answer — rather it is a tradeoff: it depends on the expected use.

Your current approach optimizes for the maximum render performance at the cost of mutation performance. By using a tree structure, no transformation is needed at render time (just iteration) — however, arbitrary node lookups within the tree can't be done in constant time.

Another approach is to store the data as an associative array of nodes (Node ID ➡️ Node — e.g. [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)/[`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)), which will optimize for arbitrary node lookup — and you can simply build the tree on every render by including each node's **child** IDs as part of its structure.

Here's an example of such a structure using the data that you provided:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/PQKhAIEEDsE9wIYAckBsCWBjBAXdB7aAWgGckBTTdAMy3ABNcFwdYLwBbAVxJ3BNzoS1eDgAWQ8CGAAoVuwBqCDPQBy+euXABecAG8Z4cKAgBVaOgCOXLdMPh09AFz8cAJ3TQA5gG57J8HU+ZVR8AHdyenAAI0oEHi18anBMQmoMTD47I0wJVHo3cmgAfhdocgA3cjc-AF8-GWBgcABNfC43RBQMwUJSCipaTAYmFjZyJzlx8ABJHHIOHX17RxdeD28-I2gEDgnXDd9-ZvIcTAA6GXqZKfYAGSEcdU0AHgAVcHIAD3noehJwEoVM9yAA+JYfABkyyMAQevHASRSeSiMwAIgDssj0PlCiU1u5PF4ANoAXXAAB9wFw-uRaOV6HUGk0oNBEdEAFaUPipaAkR5ExHJdHgADW5FgAIQf3A8KeGi0FWUNhIk3kWjlIIAssh3p8fkV-oDlI4QeDdAAFBBuPDKF4AJUo+Dc9Be6yJABpZY8Qe9Qf6GryEdAFTqkC5NaHdXMFuaYeAAER7aBcBMuAxGIyrRPJ1Me+zbXb7BNaop5gvY3FFFzEhPoeYcIgARgTXrrDaIACYE6T80Zan3E-WFs20-Gs84hx2W4PC3sXAmAEKFBCi6gIXit+wD+ztkfd9MV7N7xvd2fgHbzxN3Gm5LeZysFavgWvD0+j3vbwcnrujw8P4831-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-A3YTa6Jh9o3cHJ7qzb9pA21zBMrb8IA)

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@babel/standalone@7.20.15/babel.min.js"></script><script>Babel.registerPreset("tsx", {presets: [[Babel.availablePresets["typescript"], {allExtensions: true, isTSX: true}]]});</script>
<script type="text/babel" data-type="module" data-presets="tsx">

/** Any application-specific data type must satisfy this */
type ValidNode = {
  /** Unique */
  id: string;
  /** Not allowed because of conflict */
  children?: never;
};

// Your application-specific data type:
type Item = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  // etc.
};

type ListNode<T extends ValidNode> = T & {
  /** List of child IDs */
  children?: string[] | undefined;
};

// An object consisting of ID keys and ListNode values:
type ListNodeMap<T extends ValidNode> = Partial<Record<string, ListNode<T>>>;

const nodeMap: ListNodeMap<Item> = {
  "menu": {
    id: "menu",
    name: "Menu",
    children: ["item-1", "item-2"],
  },
  "item-1": {
    id: "item-1",
    name: "Breakfast",
  },
  "item-2": {
    id: "item-2",
    name: "Lunch",
    children: ["item-2-1"],
  },
  "item-2-1": {
    id: "item-2-1",
    name: "Irresistibly healthy",
  },
};

// A type-safe getter function which throws on bad IDs:
function getNode (
  nodeMap: ListNodeMap<Item>,
  id: string,
): ListNode<Item> {
  const node = nodeMap[id];
  if (!node) throw new Error(`Node ID ${JSON.stringify(id)} not found`);
  return node;
}

/** The "linked" version of a ListNode */
type TreeNode<T extends ValidNode> = T & {
  children?: T[] | undefined;
};

// Note: This uses recursion because it's for tree structures.
// Calling with list nodes having cyclic reference IDs will create an infinite loop.
function createTree (
  nodeMap: ListNodeMap<Item>,
  id: string,
): TreeNode<Item> {
  const node = getNode(nodeMap, id);
  return {
    ...node,
    children: node.children?.map(id => createTree(nodeMap, id)),
  };
}

console.log("node map:", nodeMap);
console.log("tree:", createTree(nodeMap, "menu"));

</script>
```

You didn't show how you receive the data, but if your API returns nodes with parent IDs instead of child IDs, then you can simply lookup each parent when acquiring new children and insert the child IDs at the time of acquisition — using an intermediate mapping structure if needed... that's tangential to the asked question.

You also didn't show how you plan to update node names, so I've excluded that part in the linked playground below, but here's an otherwise complete example of the code above with state and a reducer for updating an arbitrary node: [Full example with state and reducer in TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#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-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-EILRUajV4YAgLRjK7Eh-I1bNdGjfmMdpMgUaMEcUnhxHPm1rsjNUYXDdRwk4TQFgnnNnX2FkWN1C11G9YRmq7a7A5YwwiMnjRwaxs3Lmd3Gg86IgUXPipmb03LA4Ovt-KcHwKgl2qGrKl9mqSAkLtKmdo2TCvOBs-99GUHi4s-GXPOTBLKMQPR+YaE8rGcbxwnidJ4RKmb67WWfBBKewEh6c+HgUjrh2Smux82Q24G0fOvC-bQEs9u0Cs57WhfwMeZfzozp4SE3sBt53s+sRHvEUnHpUl22h+z9PpUqfBjM5-ok7NkeT+odnnYUyNAkBMBgJUb+UA6THxYiUGGMMZCD3gHUBKpomBlxshggO6Qz590AcINg7AkC91OtdFMIhCHEMhnPLMOYRDKg4FQwBN0XrsEqFiYQTUQCmAAIzkxEFw0wAAmYQOJqFQ3EZw+MvCSH93SOQqRrAZHiJwdmTGAAhaqvJeCt0kOIrgkjBEiLwTvUoJ5FHcJESozMajKjCGOB2Pw5NmGQluisdhFjhEyLEYAgx+CjEyJMTvBRAS+HWNoZjGEME0DsmqMAPoTBNCcWiP4Mgzi55+PSJk-KkcGYxwoYw5xFY5RUCWigA0AgwCvETF5VgMoNILWdDzQyxTE7GzKcuBAXCUBcEqGUiprUUAl1oPQZgrAODwHRpAukK456XFAV8FxXT4wRQ+mAJcxF4wcx+LM0xcBLh6D5AKJIyzWAljKFwRZezrqnJABvNRMNrnpFuU9FEHA4CrH2R07pJyuGvLcRwHg8gfgbFAUwR5ezLjyD0Fcne4MIXpChQskotFyxyDaSOVQOhlzDPEKMlghDJklCQXALEMCSDYC8GAQwCxb5EnQFgXABA4JiCZWgA6uQjDRAwai3ez4BBR1fCkP6NU+poHTmvDewMx6SoFXksGBx0jTOXGzEArwfkICxHKz4OIgVfFRTDIAA)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write such a thorough answer, @jsejcksn, and for extrapolating from my weak question. Your examples really helped. If it's not too late to ask, why did you opt to pass a function (`setNode`) to the reducer as opposed to a new node, for example? Is this a common pattern?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75452422/does-a-complex-deeply-nested-client-side-state-need-to-be-normalised/75464320?noredirect=1#comment133948699_75464320) @Check12 I think you're referring to some code in the TS playground that's not part of the answer. I'd need to spend some time reviewing the code (it's been a while) — I also likely wrote that code pretty quickly because it was not pertinent to the actual question — just some extra boilerplate related to the context. Without examination, my guess is just: "functional programming patterns".